# Making default behavior closed instead of open

Tags: jquery

I have the code:

```
$("#accordion h3.prof").next().show();
$("#accordion h3").next().hide();
$("h3.first").next().hide();
$("#accordion h3.prof").next().show();

$("#accordion h3").click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle('blind', 500);
});
```

```html
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="prof"><a href="#">Title</a></h3>
    <div class="closed-box">
        Content area that can be hidden
    </div>
</div>
```

Which creates a toggle/open close effect for boxes, when you click the `h3`. The thing is, the box is always open as default, I'd like the default behavior to be closed for only the `<div>`'s with a class of `.closed-box` - but it's just not happening. Even if I give the style display:none to .closed-box

Can someone assist please?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could add your HTML to the question or show an example of the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net. What is the `next()` element in each of these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add this in jQuery

```
$('.closed-box').hide();
```

And the default behavior was a closed box on page load.

Comment: It would be better practice to do that in CSS; `.closed-box { display: none; }`

Comment: If I added the the .js overwrites it so was ineffective.